# New project with "rails new --api" -- missing ActionDispatch::Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access the request object in app/controllers/application_controller.rb. My code is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

  protect_from_forgery

  before_action :require_login

private

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      logger.log "#{request}"
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    false
  end                                                                         
end
```

This results in the error:

```
comparison of String with 0 failed, highlighting the line logger.log "#{request}"
```

I thought it was a problem with the middleware not being loaded, so I tried to load it in config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Request
```

But this results in another error:

```
undefined method 'call' for ActionDispatch::Request
```

I seem to keep having to add things back in since I used the --api option and it strips a lot of things out. But I don't know how to add back in access to the request option. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mis-using logger.log. In the simple example below, I have outlined three ways to approach this. If you want to use logger.log, you need to specify at minimum a severity level. That is the source of the *comparison of String with 0 failed* message you are receiving.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :log_request

  def log_request
    logger.log request                     # This doesn't work
    logger.info("#{request}")              # This works
    logger.log(Logger::WARN,"#{request}")  # This works
  end

end
```

Valid levels are: FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG.

**Reference**: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-add (logger.log is an alias for logger.add)

> Logger#add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil) { ... }